# Insight on backup safety feature for linear actuator using NEMA stepper motor in commercial product?

Tags: motor, switches, stepper-motor, actuator

I am of intermediate skill level with electronics and hardware. I am working on a linear actuator concept prototype with a partner that we plan to iteratively develop and eventually take to market for in home applications. It's primary array of use is for drawers, small doors, pop out shelves, etc. We are currently using a set of small limit switches, positioned in parallel to the axis of motion, (signal lines to an Arduino controller) to control the actuator's travel bounds, operates with a NEMA 23 motor.

Several weeks ago we integrated a second set of external limit switches just a short distance beyond each of the first set. This second set runs a voltage line of the motor through these second switches before it reaches the motor. We mean for this to act as a safety feature that will shut off the motor if the traveling component goes beyond either of the intended first switch set positions.

For a number of reasons, this temporary solution will not work in the final design. Therefore, we need some other alternative to limit the travel while also ensuring safety with using the high torque motor. Ultimately, we would like to have a single limit switch or other electromechanical component that limits the travel length while also ensuring safety under operation from the high torque motor.

My question is:

How do other similar commercially available products that use high torque motors accomplish this while ensuring safety? Are additional fuses, switches, or relays typically used in combination to prevent catastrophic failures? How can we guarantee the motor will stop when it hits the switch or component, even if there is a hardware failure or software error?

Thank you for reading my post. I greatly appreciate any insight.

Comment: This doesn't really sound like an application where a stepper motor is needed or suitable.  They certainly aren't "high torque" compared to more typical budget solutions such as gearmotors.  Ironically a stepper solutions is likely to be weak enough that crashing into a physical stop could work, but it's really not how such a product would be built.  You should probably focus on fixing the limit switch issues, probably considering a broader range of mounting options.  Really this is a mechanical engineering problem not an electrical engineering one.

Comment: When you mention "safety", my thought is first that a small (relatively fragile) child or a pet dog, cat, snake, rat, whatever could get crushed or perhaps have their windpipe compressed and thus asphyxiate from pressure caused by your motor-driven door or drawer. The "health" of the device is really secondary unless it could somehow catch fire, electrocute or emit toxic smoke to poison living things.

Comment: Our current rig moves 160 lbs (w/ safety factor) horizontally at a speed that one may expect a door/drawer to open... So under 10 seconds or so for about 15" of travel, as to not completely inconvenience and bore the owner over a simple operation. Granted that our rig is already geared down 1:3, we are still pushing a 2.7A 0.8 deg bipolar NEMA 23 to its limit. What exactly am I missing that makes this approach not suitable, aside from our difference in interpretation of the meaning of "high torque" ? It drives a 4mm dia. lead screw, so if it crashes, its not going to stop peacefully at all.

Comment: you should first read and understand the standards for functional safety, see if you need to conform to them and then validate if your mechanical concept is allowed according to the standards... I doubt it.

Comment: @schnedan, thanks for that lead. Can you please elaborate on your doubt? The standards won't really help me on how to come up with an alternative, which is the reason for this posts.

Comment: @treked011 how do you detect jaming / blocking? in industry you normally use light curtains or doors to block access to moving parts controlled by a safety PLC. If that is not possible you combine at least 2 different kinds of sensors to detect movement e.g. a resistive and a magnetic way messurement or an optical plus a resistive,...depending on the mechanic used you might also use the motor current to detect blocking

Comment: @treked011 also if there is a possibility for a human to get harmed, movement is normally very slow plus one must reach a kill switch (also wired according to functional safety standards)

Comment: @treked011 also note, any scissors-like mechanic might convert minimal movements into huge torque, causing huge injuries

Comment: @schnedan what you're asking in essence points to what Spehro Pefhany previously commented and what you said about functional safety standards. I don't really know the answer:  does this class of stepper motor and application we are pursuing actually need the level of safety that we think it does? To some, a NEMA 23 is not much, but considering our targeted requirements, we think it's pretty substantial.

Comment: Well you say you want to move "drawers, small doors, pop out shelves"... so to me that sounds like people can interact with these while moving. And to me this means: safety standards apply. So one of the fist things these standards demand is a risk analysis - for normal function as well as for failing parts. If your risk analysis result e.g. forces are so low, not even a baby might get hurt, you do not need to go further... if the risk analysis reveals unacceptable risk you need to make sure the risk is minimized to a acceptable level

Comment: @treked011 - well I just did a quick research with google... DIN IEC 60335-2-116 seems to be in draft state "Household and similar electrical appliances - Safety - Part 2-116: Particular requirements for furniture with electrically motorized parts" - https://www.techstreet.com/standards/din-iec-60335-2-116-draft?product_id=2015889

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/113383/discussion-between-treked011-and-schnedan).